# How are "ShareIt","Xender" etc able to install APK without requiring "unknown source" permission?

Tags: apk, unknown-sources, shareit

Normally, if I have to install an apk(say from SD card), I need to enable “Unknown Sources” in my phone's settings. But when I transfer and install any APK from another phone using "ShareIt", no such permission is required by my phone.

How is ShareIt able to bypass this permission?

Comment: Did ShareIt come pre-installed on your device, or did you install it yourself?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I did a bit of digging and it is possible without System permissions from API 21 onwards https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInstaller.html.

In fact, there is a code sample by Google which shows how to do it. https://github.com/googlesamples/android-testdpc/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/afwsamples/testdpc/cosu/CosuUtils.java

Comment: Kudos for digging this up, now to find whether the app actually used this...

Comment: @beeshyams - Not really. The app cannot do a "silent" install. Through the pending intent, the user's explicit "click" is required at the time of installation.

Comment: @Neo Damn, so I just assumed a silent install when I wrote my answer... My bad.

Comment: In other news, the package of ShareIt seems to be somehow obfuscated, so even though my tools succeeded in the Java code generation, nothing significant can be seen from the stubs.

Comment: Wait - I used another tool, and I think I might've got it. I'll have it edited into your answer after verification.

Comment: Scratch that, there are references to PackageInstaller and its sessions, but nothing directly related to installing. Still a dead end. Sorry for false hopes and disturbing you with notifications.

Answer (score 4):

If the apps are installed silently (i.e.without the usual installation dialog), presumably these apps directly call `pm`, i.e. `PackageManager`, which as a system app bears the permission [`android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#INSTALL_PACKAGES).

The phone has to be rooted so the app could call `pm` in a root context, else you will be greeted with the message "Neither user xxxx nor current process has android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES".

EDIT: As @Izzy pointed out in the comment, `android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES` is also granted to apps installed to `/system`. See below comment and [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14348066/systemorsignature-protection-level) for more insight.

Comment: Note that I didn't actually try ShareIt and analyse what it really does, just putting forward the most likely theory. If you are not rooted and it still worked, then we might have a much more interesting problem to look into.

Comment: wondering, even if the phone is rooted, can the app grab SU permission at **install** time? That would be scary and goes against what little I know of SU stuff

Comment: I used SHAREit once, in desperation to transfer some files to iOS and promptly uninstalled it. It didn't ask for root permissions. This was a couple of months ago and OP could be talking of a letter app version

Comment: @beeshyams In China here, a lot of 3rd party app markets would do silent or automated install. The 1st way is as described here, and they will ask for root permission on first install; the 2nd is to ask you to turn on an accessibility service, then automate the clicks on the "install" buttons.

Comment: My phone is not rooted. And it did not ask for root permissions either. But in India, ShareIt is a very popular method of installing apps through peer-to-peer.

Comment: That's new to me. Please edit your question to include this detail, so that others could take it into consideration later when they come up with a better answer. I might have to try that app myself and grab a log when it's running to see what fuss it hides behind.

Comment: @beeshyams Avoid that app and its horrendous mole of required permissions. Consider using the open source [Share via HTTP](https://f-droid.org/app/com.MarcosDiez.shareviahttp) (available on F-Droid), instead. *I'm in no way affiliated with the app.*

Comment: @beeshyams It works with any device connected to the same network. As far as I can tell, the host must be Android, but any device can then connect to the same network and visit the HTTP address shown in the app to download the file(s).

Comment: Note that if an app comes pre-installed (i.e. it is a system app), it can do silent installs – as [`INSTALL_PACKAGES`](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/perms#INSTALL_PACKAGES) is defined with protectionLevel "SystemOrSignature". So if ShareIt came pre-installed on the device (which it sometimes is), this is a very likely scenario. No root needed for that then. (Andy: You might wish to include this fact with your answer, as only few will read up to this comment ;)